# Loop through showing/hiding React components on a timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'm trying to show or hide a series of "pages" on a timer; in other words every x seconds, render a new group of components.

```
const PAGES = [[<Component1 />, <Component2 />], [<Component3 />, <Component4 />]];

export default class MyDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { index: -1 };
  }

  renderPages() {
    console.log(this.state.index);
    return PAGES[this.state.index];
  }

  setIndex() {
    let index = this.state.index > PAGES.length ? 0 : this.state.index + 1;
    this.setState({ index: index });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loop = setInterval(this.setIndex(), 3000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.loop);
  }

  render() {
    return <Dashboard layout={CustomLayout}>{this.renderPages()}</Dashboard>;
  }
}
```

I'm using the [Dashbling](https://github.com/pascalw/dashbling) framework, but essentially I have an array, `PAGES`, which is a list of arrays. (I've verified that you can indeed render an array of components, so that's not a problem.)

I'm using the state to store the `index`, updated with `setIndex()`, which will increase until it surpasses `PAGES.length` at which point it will reset to 0.

I put `setIndex()` inside `setInterval()` in the hopes that it would call it every x seconds, thus displaying a new group of components, but it only displays the first page, then stops. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` expects a function as its first argument. You are committing a common mistake of passing it the *return value* of the function (which is `undefined`), while calling it just once when the component mounts.

Just remove those parentheses:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loop = setInterval(this.setIndex, 3000);
}
```

except that the value of `this` will be lost inside the `setIndex` method when it is called, so in fact you will also need to ensure the correct `this` is passed. You can do this using the `bind` method, or as shown below, with an arrow function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loop = setInterval(() => this.setIndex(), 3000);
}
```

Comment: How would you use it with bind? `this.loop = setInterval(this.setIndex().bind(this), 3000)`?

Comment: yes, except without the parentheses (once again, `bind` is a method that *functions* have, and `this.setIndex()` is not the function itself but the value returned from it): `this.loop = setInterval(this.setIndex.bind(this), 3000)`. Note also that you can do this in the component's constructor: `this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this)` which is recommended in the official React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). If you do that then the code in my first snippet will work. (But there's nothing wrong with using the arrow function instead.)

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```js
this.loop = setInterval(() => this.setIndex(), 3000);
```

not this

```js
this.loop = setInterval(this.setIndex(), 3000);
```

Comment: That worked!! Is this just the proper syntax for `setInterval()`, or am I missing something deeper?

Comment: @mbj hopefully my answer explains it, it's not really a syntax issue, it's because `setInterval` expects a function. `() => this.setIndex()` is a function, `this.setIndex()` is not (it's `undefined`)

Comment: @mbj `setInterval(fn, time)` takes a function as its first parameter. `this.setIndex` is a variable that is also a function. `this.setIndex()` is running the function and giving `setInterval` that result, which isn't a function.